# Making function same as strlen() in C with only #include<stdio.h> (no other header)

Tags: c, stdio

I'm going to have a test in next week. And in the sheet they say that "You can't use strlen() in test"
How can I make it.

Can use only  ONLY!!!

Comment: Read up on what strlen does. It should be easy to figure out a simple implementation from that.

Comment: A lot of 'experienced' developers seem to now know what strlen() does.  It looks for a null in a raly big array or at the end of an incrementing pointer.

Comment: Could you be barking up the wrong tree? If the test says that you can't use `strlen`, that might be an indicator that you don't need it in the solution rather than an invitation to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

```
size_t my_strlen(const char *s){
    const char *p=s;
    while(*p)
        ++p;
    return p-s;
}
```

Comment: While tecnically perfect, size_t is defined in stddef.h and might therfore violate the specified requirement to only use stdio.h

Comment: @RonPinkas It seems to be no problem, for example, from being used in functions such as `fread` (in <stdio.h> `size_t fread(void * restrict ptr,size_t size,size_t nmemb,FILE * restrict stream);`).

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int strlen(const char* temp)
{
    int i=0;
    while(*(temp++)) ++i;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    char *text = "Hello World";
    printf("%d",strlen(text));
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
unsigned long mystrlen( const char *szString )
{
   unsigned long ulLen = 0;

   While( szString[0]){ szString++; ulLen++;}

   return ulLen;
}
```